# R: String match from column1 selects data from column2's rows to create column3?

Tags: r, string

I am trying to get a string match from `column1` and then select only that data from the corresponding rows of `column2`  in order to create a `column3` with the data from those string-matched rows of `column2`.

I hope this is clear.

Example:
Partial string `"dog"`

```
DF
#   Column1      column2  column3
#1    doggy            x        x
#2      cat            y       
#3     bird            y
#4    doggy            z        z
#5      cat            x
#6     bird            y
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` with `grepl` :

```
transform(df, column3 = ifelse(grepl('dog', Column1), column2, ''))

#  Column1 column2 column3
#1   doggy       x       x
#2     cat       y        
#3    bird       y        
#4   doggy       z       z
#5     cat       x        
#6    bird       y
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Column1 = c("doggy", "cat", "bird", "doggy", "cat", 
"bird"), column2 = c("x", "y", "y", "z", "x", "y")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks! Ok, noob question: Im not seeing column3 as a variable in my global environment. Now that i have column3 'transformed', how do i use it?

Comment: You don't see column names as variable in global environment. Assign the data back to `df`,  `df <- transform(df, column3 = ifelse(grepl('dog', Column1), column2, ''))`. Now you can see the changed `df`.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok. Something so simple, but now i understand a big missing piece that was confusing me in R. Thank you so much! Coffee!

Answer (score 2):

We can accomplish this with the `dplyr` and `stringr` packages.

Use `mutate` to create the new `column3` variable.

`case_when` allows you to vectorise `if_else()`. It is a two-sided formula that uses `str_detect` to detect the presence of the provided pattern in `Column1`. If the pattern is present, the value in `column2` is returned in `column3`. If the pattern is not present, no value is returned (signified by the `TRUE ~ ""` portion.

Thanks for the data, Ronak!

```r
df <- structure(list(Column1 = c("doggy", "cat", "bird", "doggy", "cat", 
"bird"), column2 = c("x", "y", "y", "z", "x", "y")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    column3 = case_when(
      str_detect(Column1, "dog") ~ column2,
      TRUE ~ ""
    )
  )

#>   Column1 column2 column3
#> 1   doggy       x       x
#> 2     cat       y        
#> 3    bird       y        
#> 4   doggy       z       z
#> 5     cat       x        
#> 6    bird       y
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>